# Android Wear: Package Wear app for some product flavours

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os, android-productflavors

I have an Android handheld app with a couple of product flavours and 1 wear module. I need to only package this wear app with flavour1 and **not** flavour2.

As I understand this, adding the wear module as a dependency would include it in both flavour1 and flavour2.

I'm aware I could build the wear app manually and then add it to the flavour1's res/raw directory and have a res/xml/wearable_app_desc.xml containing the app's version and path details as outlined here:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually

But this seems like manual work and I was hoping there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if your flavors are **flavorA** and **flavorB**,
you can easily do so, 
when u link it correctly in the ***build.gradle***

Means:

```
flavorAWearApp project(':WearAppProject')
```

All the best, hope this is what u want,
Mike